# Asymptotic stability of Continuous Time Markov Chains (CTMCs)

Tags: stochastic-processes

The evolution of the state occupancy probabilities of a CTMC can be described
by a linear system of differential equations of the form  $\dot{\mathbf{x}} = A.\mathbf{x}$.

The rate matrix A usually has a 0 zero eigenvalue.

Therefore, A violates the Routh-Hurwitz Criterion (RHC) for asymptotic stability.  RHC mandates all the eigenvalues of a matrix to have strictly negative real parts.

Does this mean that CTMCs are not asymptotically stable?  To be precise, the equilibria
of CTMCs is not asymptotically stable?

Thank you.

Comment: [Routh-Hurwitz theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routh%E2%80%93Hurwitz_theorem) assumes no roots on the imaginary line, hence A violates nothing, it seems.